# npx react-native init error does not contain a package.json file in appdata folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, npx

when I use regular npm or npx commands like

```
npm -version
```

or

```
npx -version
```

there is no error, but for my react native project when I use

```
npx react-native init testApp
```

it shows this error:

```
does not contain a package.json file in appdata folder
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

this error occurs usually when name of the PC contain a space. like

```
mycomputer name
```

you should fix this by redefine your npm cache root
try:

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\mycomputer~1name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

be careful for space character in the pc name you should use "~1" instead

good luck

Comment: It as created another directory `mycomputer~1name` under `C:\Users` along with `mycomputer name`

Answer (score 1):

**This is because of the space in your computer's name**, and besides working around your computer's namespace, you can also try installing the create-react-app globally as `npm i -g create-react-app` and then run your `npx create-react-app your-app-name` command again, this solved it for me!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Change cache folder.

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use,

```
npx create-react-app yourAppName
```

Comment: It creates **React JS** project instead of **React Native** project

Answer (score -2):

```
$ npx create-react-app your project name
```